# Qt - Associative arrays

Tags: arrays, qt, hash, associative, named

Is possible to create an associative array (hash or named arrays) in Qt?

Something like:

```
int array[2];

array["text1"] = 10;
array["text2"] = 20;
```

Comment: use QHash http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QHash<QString, int>
```

Or if you need lower or upper bounds

```
QMap<QString, int>
```